# Key value observation on discrete data derived from a continuous data

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

So I have two properties defined

```
@property (nonatomic) float continous;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger discrete;
```

`continous` is an actual property that varies continously, while the getter for `discrete` looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)discrete {
  return floor(continuous);
}
```

So, now I want to KVO on `discrete`, of course, I need to implement the following in my class:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingDiscrete {
  return [NSSet setWithObject:NSStringFromSelector(continuous)];
}
```

Now, the problem is that since `continuous` is constantly changing, KVO would constantly send out updates, even though `discrete` has not actually changed! For example, KVO would keep updating me as `continous` varies from 0 to 0.9, but during this process, `discrete` is always `0`. Now I don't really want that, is there anyway to only make KVO fire up changes when `discrete` has actually changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than making a derived property for `discrete`, you could make it a stored property which is publicly `readonly` but privately `readwrite`. Implement the setter for `continuous` yourself, like so:

```
- (void) setContinuous:(float)newValue
{
    _continuous = newValue;
    NSInteger newDiscrete = floor(_continuous);
    if (newDiscrete != _discrete)
        self.discrete = newDiscrete;
}
```